# <button> with no text inside appears higher

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a spinner within a button to indicate that an action is loading. the problem is that if a button has no text in it, it will appear higher than the rest of the buttons, and I want them to be aligned.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>

<button class='buttonclass'>aaa</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>
<span class="loader"></span>
</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>bbb</button>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.buttonclass {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 3px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: spin 0.75s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(315deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

and this is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF43G.png)

I want all 3 buttons to be aligned, is it possible? thanks

Comment: Have you try to add `vertical-align` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Flexbox can help you out there. My approach with commented code:

```css
div {
  width: 200px; /*just for the example*/
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;/*vertical alignment*/
  justify-content: space-between;/* spacing / horizontal alignment*/
}

.buttonclass {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 3px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: spin 0.75s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(315deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>

<button class='buttonclass'>aaa</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>
<span class="loader"></span>
</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>bbb</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex on the first `div` like that:

```css
.buttonclass {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 3px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: spin 0.75s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(315deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.first{ display:flex; }
```

```html
<div class="first">

<button class='buttonclass'>aaa</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>
<span class="loader"></span>
</button>

<button class='buttonclass'>bbb</button>

</div>
```

Comment: we answered pretty simultaneously, is my answer to similar? should i delete it?

Comment: i think is same, you just add space :) but how you want.

Comment: i'll leave it there in case the spacing is useful for the Person with the Question too, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here an example

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   let loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
   btn.classList.add("disabled");
   loader.style.display = "block";
})
```

```css
.buttonclass {
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 300ms;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loader {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 2px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation: spin 0.45s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(315deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.disabled {
   background: lightgrey;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid lightgrey;
   pointer-events: none;
   outline: none;
   color: grey;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonclass">Click me<div class="loader"></div></button>
```